# How to find tar format of archive?

Tags: tar

There are several formats of tar archives, `ustar`, `gnu`, etc.  Is there some tool that can show which format a given archive is in?  (Haven't found it in manpage of `bsdtar` nor in info pages of GNU tar).

Comment: Are you sure these actually produce different formats? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)#Format_details implies that tar files follow POSIX IEEE P1003.1

Comment: I normally just use : file <filename.tar>  . I get (for example) : ./dojo-release-1.5.0.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Comment: Running `tar --help` I find out that it defaults to "--format=gnu".  The generated file is not accepted on hackage.haskell.org with the message that it isn't in `ustar` format.

Answer (score 3):

As @FreudianSlip mentioned in the comments you can use `file` on an unix command line to check the format.

```sh
$ file archive.tar 
archive.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open it then click `Info` button.
It will show information about compression methods and so on.
[image: Click on Info button]
By far 7Zip isn't the only program which can do it (it's my choice because it's open source and free),  a lot of archivers can do the same.

Comment: That's good to know, but for home I'd really like a way that doesn't require me to first go out buying a license for an OS I don't particularly like :)

Comment: @Magnus Which OS do you use? As I know there are a lot of versions for various systems (look [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)), but I'm not sure if they have UI.

Comment: I'm on Linux and I have the CLI version of `7z` installed, but it offers no way to extract that information AFAICS.